# wcf (webhttpbinding) calling via jquery - asp.net session not populated

Tags: wcf

I'm farily new to wcf and was hoping someone could help. I have a wcf project and a web app.
Wcf project is hosted as an app in IIS in the web project both using the same app pool.

I've added sessionmode.allowed to my wcf interface, enabled aspnetcompatibilitymode. For the binding i've set transport as the security and have tried allowcookies as false and true.

When i hit the site and check keys in the session there's about 5, however when it then calls via jquery to my service and i check keys in the session there is none. It seems like the cookies aren't getting sent for every request.

Has anyone experienced similar behaviour?

Thanks

Comment: This could be problem with WCF and ASP.Net application hosted in different domain. Have you cheked that?

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't even aware that that was possible, so I just set up my own test project.
And session state worked fine for me.

If it helps, here is the code I wrote that works:

```
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Activation;
using System.ServiceModel.Web;
using System.Web;

[ServiceContract(Namespace = "")]
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
public class MyService
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebGet]
    public string DoWork()
    {
        var httpContext = HttpContext.Current;
        var sessionState = httpContext.Session;

        return (string)sessionState["Foo"]; // This returns "Bar"
                                            // which I set in the Page_Load 
                                            // server method
    }
}
```

An in my default page's Load method:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    System.Web.SessionState.HttpSessionState sessionState = this.Session;
    sessionState["Foo"] = "Bar";
}
```

And in my web.config file:

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="MyServiceAspNetAjaxBehavior">
          <enableWebScript/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment 
           aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" 
           multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
    <services>
      <service name="MyService">
        <endpoint 
              address="" 
              behaviorConfiguration="MyServiceAspNetAjaxBehavior"
              binding="webHttpBinding" 
              contract="MyService"/>
      </service>
    </services>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: Thanks Andrew, The only thing i could see different between mine and yours is that you're using .net 4 and enableWebScript. Where i am using .net 3.5 and webhttp. I changed mine to enablescript but with no luck which is weird. Out of curiosity is your wcf service hosted in IIS ? I'm also running it under SSL buti don't think that's the issue. If i self host the wcf it works.

Comment: I'm running this all in my Visual Studio debugger, so I haven't tested it in IIS. That always opens up a raft of unexpected issues!